# OutOfMemoryException while while opening OracleConnection

Tags: c#, oracle, out-of-memory

A coworker and I got the task to fix an problem on a SQL-Client.
The error is a **System.OutOfMemoryException**.

I figured that it could be because of the client has to many connections that doesn't get closed properly.

I tested a bit around but I can't seem to get it working.

Anyone have a suggestion?

This is the code where the error happens:

```
        public void SQLIntoDataGridView(OracleCommand cmd, int startIndex, int maxIndex, int ersteSpalte, int maxSpalten, DataTable datenTabelle, DataGridView dgv, int sqlNr, DataTable dt)
    {
        OracleConnection test = new OracleConnection();

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int spalten = ersteSpalte;
        int id;
        int spaltenZaehler = ersteSpalte;
        int maxrows = datenTabelle.Rows.Count;
        int readZeile = 0;
        int writeZeile = 0;
        int startrow = 0;
        int startSpalte = 0;
        int endSpalte = 0;

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        test.ConnectionString = "Data Source=; User ID=; Password=";

        using (test)
        {

            if (test.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                test.Open(); // <-- this is where the error occures

            using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                datenTabelle.Load(reader);
                dataGridViewErgebnis.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridViewTest.DataSource = datenTabelle;
                dataGridViewErweitern(sqlNr);
                #region Rechnungsempfänger X
                if (startIndex == 27 || startIndex == 24)
                {
                    while (j < dataGridViewErgebnis.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        id = startIndex;
                        if (dataGridViewErgebnis.Rows[j].Cells[21].Value.ToString() == "")
                        {
                            readZeile++;
                            i = readZeile;
                            j++;
                            writeZeile++;
                        }
                        else if (dataGridView1.Rows[startrow].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == dataGridViewErgebnis.Rows[j].Cells[21].Value.ToString())
                        {
                            if (startIndex == 24)
                            {
                                startSpalte = 7;
                                endSpalte = 9;
                                spaltenZaehler = startSpalte;
                            }
                            else if (startIndex == 27)
                            {
                                startSpalte = 10;
                                endSpalte = 14;
                                spaltenZaehler = startSpalte;
                            }
                            spaltenZaehler = startSpalte;
                            maxSpalten = endSpalte;
                            while (spaltenZaehler <= maxSpalten)
                            {
                                i = startrow;
                                dataGridViewErgebnis.Rows[writeZeile].Cells[id].Value = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[spaltenZaehler].Value.ToString();
                                spaltenZaehler++;
                                id++;
                            }
                            readZeile++;
                            i = readZeile;
                            j++;
                            writeZeile++;
                            spaltenZaehler = startSpalte;
                            startrow = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            startrow++;
                        }
                        if (i == dt.Rows.Count - 1 && j == datenTabelle.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            id = startIndex;
                            while (id <= maxIndex && spaltenZaehler <= maxSpalten)
                            {
                                dataGridViewErgebnis.Rows[writeZeile].Cells[id].Value = dataGridViewTest.Rows[i].Cells[spaltenZaehler].Value.ToString();
                                id++;
                                spaltenZaehler++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion
                else
                {
                    while (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        id = startIndex;
                        if (dataGridViewErgebnis.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == dataGridViewTest.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                        {
                            while (spaltenZaehler <= maxSpalten)
                            {
                                dataGridViewErgebnis.Rows[i].Cells[id].Value = dataGridViewTest.Rows[j].Cells[spaltenZaehler].Value.ToString();
                                spaltenZaehler++;
                                id++;
                            }
                            if (startIndex == 10 && j == datenTabelle.Rows.Count - 1)
                            {
                                j--;
                                j--;
                                i++;
                            }
                            if (j <= datenTabelle.Rows.Count - 1)
                            {
                                j++;
                            }
                            spaltenZaehler = ersteSpalte;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            i++;
                            while (id <= maxIndex)
                            {
                                dataGridViewErgebnis.Rows[i].Cells[id].Value = "";
                                id++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (i == dt.Rows.Count - 1 && j == datenTabelle.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            id = startIndex;
                            while (id <= maxIndex && spaltenZaehler <= maxSpalten)
                            {
                                dataGridViewErgebnis.Rows[i].Cells[id].Value = dataGridViewTest.Rows[j].Cells[spaltenZaehler].Value.ToString();
                                id++;
                                spaltenZaehler++;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (j == datenTabelle.Rows.Count && startIndex != 10)
                        {
                            j--;
                            if (i <= dt.Rows.Count - 2)
                            {
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                watch.Stop();
                StoppUhr(watch);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest editing your title to "*while opening OracleConnection*" instead of "*while getting data from database*"

Comment: If you crash on test.Open() only, the rest of your code seems to be unimportant.
OutOfMemory is very unlikely than opening a connection. This could be a recursive call. Are you sure this function is not calling itself indirectly ? Or there are some side effects taking place, like cashing some data, when opening a connection.

Comment: As you are in a "using" statement, it takes care of closing the connection. No need to handle this.

I would focus on checking the connection to be available and the process has enough resources to serve the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite the code like this.

```
.
.
.
OracleConnection test = new OracleConnection();
.
.
.

        using (OracleConnection test = new OracleConnection("Data Source=; User ID=; Password=")) // <-- SQLconnection here
        {

            test.Open(); // <-- Only Open connection

            using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
.
.
.
            }
         }
```

Comment: Work's like a charm :)
Thank you!